# Independent t-tests and Technical Indicators: Voodoo, Axes, and Objectivity

Tags: time-series, t-test, experiment-design, finance

First off, I'm not trying to crowd source a personal printing press (i.e., not doing this: "I'm using strategies $x$, $y$, $z$ in the stock market and...").  Instead, I'm looking for feedback on research design.

The situation: Many equity/currency/futures traders use technical analysis as part of their trading approach. Technical analysis uses past price patterns to make predictions about future prices. Technical indicators quantify that past movement. Lots of practitioners swear by the techniques. Many academics and others call [BS](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0812975219).

So, I want to test whether various technical indicators have predictive value:  Do asset prices move as these indicators predict?  I'd like to be very focused and just use independent t-tests as follows:

1. Select an indicator (e.g., [MACD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MACD)—moving average convergence/divergence).
2. Review the claims about the indicator's predictive value (e.g., MACD bullish cross indicates imminent upward trend).
3. Collect the price movement of an asset (stock/future/currency/etc.) and subset that data based on the indicator's value prior to the price movement. (e.g., IV: price movement following a bullish cross vs. price movement at times not following a bullish cross).
4. If we have a significantly unequal number of observations for each group (this will almost always happen), randomly select data from the larger population so that our number of observations are equal.
5. Run an independent samples t-test to compare the means of each group.  (I'll also Shapiro-Wilks and Levene test the data, and adjust as necessary.) We'll test the null that the sample means are not significantly different.
6. If we reject the null, look at the effect size, etc.
7. Repeat 1-6 for the most popular indicators (or until my wife asks me to come watch *Dancing with the Stars* with her (and I pretend it's a favor even though it's not that bad)).

Now, I know technical indicators are used in combinations, and some kind of moderating effect could be going on.  But I wanted to start simple.  Thoughts on how reliable this approach would be?  Potential pitfalls?

Also, full disclosure on the axe I may be grinding:  I'm leery of the very fat tails and their unmitigated positions for/against technical analysis.  I think brokerages and hucksters use them as noisy, noisy bells and whistles as they compete for clients. For most clients, the indicators do nothing.  On the other hand, I also think there's value, but what value technical indicators have is likely greatest on short time frames and perhaps better for currencies.